# MySQL 5.7 on ReadOnlyMedia

Tags: mysql, readonly

I have to set up an MySQL, that is running on a read only media, like DVD or so.
Based on the document from MySql https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-read-only-instance.html it seems not so difficult.

But whith the configuration described, it's not possible to start the server from an ISO file.

My parameters to start the server:

```
mysql-5.7.17-win32\bin\mysqld.exe --no-defaults --console --port=3307 --innodb-read-only=1 --event-scheduler=disabled --innodb_change_buffering=none --innodb_flush_method=normal --pid-file=d:\mysql.pid
```

Unfortunately this isn't working.
I will get the log:

```
2017-02-24T18:23:33.913117Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2017-02-24T18:23:33.913117Z 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled
2017-02-24T18:23:33.914120Z 0 [Note] mysql-5.7.17-win32\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 5.7.17) starting as process 9468 ...
2017-02-24T18:23:33.916995Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file G:\mysql-5.7.17-win32\data\MyComputer.lower-test
2017-02-24T18:23:33.917497Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file G:\mysql-5.7.17-win32\data\MyComputer.lower-test
2017-02-24T18:23:33.919531Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Started in read only mode
2017-02-24T18:23:33.919531Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2017-02-24T18:23:33.920004Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2017-02-24T18:23:33.920004Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2017-02-24T18:23:33.920004Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2017-02-24T18:23:33.920504Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2017-02-24T18:23:33.921007Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-02-24T18:23:33.921007Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Disabling background log and ibuf IO write threads.
2017-02-24T18:23:33.923041Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2017-02-24T18:23:33.928551Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-02-24T18:23:33.951319Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2017-02-24T18:23:34.109640Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2017-02-24T18:23:34.110647Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 5 in a file operation.
2017-02-24T18:23:34.110647Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to the directory. It may also be you have created a subdirectory of the same name as a data file.
2017-02-24T18:23:34.110647Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile '.\ibtmp1'
2017-02-24T18:23:34.110647Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to create the shared innodb_temporary
2017-02-24T18:23:34.110647Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Cannot open a file
2017-02-24T18:23:34.414731Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2017-02-24T18:23:34.414731Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2017-02-24T18:23:34.415619Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
2017-02-24T18:23:34.415619Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2017-02-24T18:23:34.416141Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2017-02-24T18:23:34.416141Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2017-02-24T18:23:34.416640Z 0 [Note] mysql-5.7.17-win32\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete
```

It's correct that the shared tablespace could not be created. We are on a read only media.

But how can I avoid the creation of the shared tablespace or let it create in a temp folder on a readable media?

Comment: SQLite seems like a much better approach for this.

Comment: Unfortunately SQLite is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

- First, you need to create your instance on a writable media,
- Do a slow shutdown as described in the reference document,
- Copy/burn or whatever your database files to your "non-writable"
  media
- Change the configuration parameters to reflect the new configuration : datadir, innodb_data_home_dir, ....
- Restart your instance

et voilà

Comment: That's the way I've done this. The problem is that the ibtmp1 file was created in the data dir which was read only. I've found the parameter innodb_temp_data_file_path to rename this file, but I couldn't set a path for example in the temp dir. It was always a subdir from data dir, which is still read only.